# Is it possible to do any GUI action on C++ class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some design related doubts. In my IOS application if I want to create any view from an c++ class(extension changed to .mm) Is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  I am developing an OS X App which has 30 .mm files and no .m files.  However .mm files are Objective-C++, not C++ (.cpp).

Here's an example of using a C++ class (defined in `cppclass.h`) within an Objective-C++ class (defined/declared in `mmclass.{h,mm}`):

cppclass.h:

```
#include <string>

class MyCppClass
{
protected:
    std::string _name;

public:
    MyCppClass() :
        _name()
    {
    }

    void setName(const std::string &name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
};
```

mmclass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cppclass.h"

@interface MyMMClass : NSObject
{
    MyCppClass _myCppClass;
}

@end
```

mmclass.mm:

```
#import "mmclass.h"

@implementation MyMMClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _myCppClass.setName("Andy");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I have changed just extension to .mm however inside the file I'm using  normal C++ concept I have created class like class sample {...} like that. In this case do you think its possible?

Comment: @FerozMohideen Yes that's possible, however if they are pure C++ why not use the file extension `.cpp`?  For actual UI classes you will certainly want to use the extension `.mm`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to create cpp instance variable in objective C files. If I declare any object inside @inteface it showing many errors. Can we do like that?

Comment: You will need to `#import` the C++ header file and don't forget the `namespace` (if you have used one).  Other than that you should have no issues.  I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I will try :)